# WKWebView error calling any javascript in iOS 10 while debugging

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, wkwebview, swift2

Fun error that ONLY happens in iOS 10, when debugging on a physical device.  It does not happen in the simulator, or when running on the physical device (while not debugging).  It also does not happen on an iOS 9 device in any situation...only iOS 10 while debugging and after any javascript call has been executed.

I have a hybrid web app, written in Swift 2.3, after the xwebview loads I call various javascript methods...actually, any in this case.  Anyway, after the javascript method has finished I get a malloc error saying I'm trying to free a pointer.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1740b5060: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

So I set the break point...and it never breaks on the breakpoint, it just keeps telling me to set a breakpoint.

If I remove all of my javascript calls, the error never happens.  I've tried enabling them one by one, it doesn't matter, they all break after the callback returns.

I've been after this for about 2 weeks, I'm out of extra hair to pull out.  At this point I'd love to hear if someone else is seeing the same thing.

Comment: I experienced the same problem. Everything was working fine before using Swift 3. When I remove the parameters from my js functions the error seems to be gone. Unfortunately I could find any solution for this problem so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like its a safari bug and therefore only appears when you are debugging your webview with safari. In Safari under Develop->Your_Device_Name **uncheck** "Automatically Show Web Inspector for JSContexts".
This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  I was a little slow, but I also started to notice the error didn't happen when Safari wasn't running...which led to your fix.